# Perl to Python , Match Pattern on a html output

Tags: python, regex, perl

How I can do the following block of code from perl to python?

```perl
while ($content2 =~ m{services</B></TD>\s<TD>\s<TABLE>\s<TR>(.*?)</TABLE>}gs) {
  my $service=$1
  print " service : $1\n";
}
```

The full code have more regex outputs than that, but with that example I'm able to proceed with the conversion.

Comment: Ew. Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser like lxml.html or BeautifulSoup.

Comment: `How I can do the following block of code from perl to python?` Doesn't say it has to be the same technique. Use a parser as Colin suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm reading your regex right, you have a table with a single row (and no data cell) inside a table-data cell. What kind of abomination are you cooking up here?

In python you'd use lxml for this. It's a real parser, so it won't fail when whitespace or casing or other unrelated structure of the document changes. It's not a part of the standard library, but it's one of (if not /the/) most-installed libraries on pypi.

```
abominable_html = '''
<html>
<table><tr><td>services</B></TD>
    <TD>
        <TABLE> <TR>Interesting stuff!</TABLE>
'''

from lxml.html import fromstring
doc = fromstring(abominable_html)

# These are equivalent, for demonstration purposes.
print doc.xpath('//table/tr/td/table/tr/text()')[0]
print doc.xpath('//table//table/tr')[0].text
```

As you can see, it deals with questionable html admirably.

---

If you need match the "services" text, you can add a condition like so:

```
print doc.xpath('//table[./tr/td="services"]//table/tr')[0].text
```

Here are some good xpath references:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev (just read the examples)
- http://our.umbraco.org/media/upload/0562fd58-c6db-4fa8-a432-68b28f11c3f2/rs/7x1B0.gif
- http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XPath_1.html

Comment: I followed your advice. and now im seeking for more info regarding lxml.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Im still learning about that :)

well, what i have basicaly is,  the content extracted by (.*?) are dynamic values (service names ), wich i need to insert into a database ( in perl i have that working ).

What i need basicaly is to extract the content betwen the tags ( wich is dynamic )

As an example bellow, with regex i can extract the name of the service, and if its enabled or not

```
$content2 =~ m{<TD valign="top"><B>name</B></TD>\s<TD>(.*?)</TD>\s</TR>\s<TR>\s<TD valign="top"><B>enabled</B></TD>\s<TD>(.*?)</TD>}gs
$service=$1
$status=$2
```

is there a way i can do that using a parser? If yes, i belive the better way is to close this question and open a new one .